# cannot figure out why System.out.println isn't working

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using this code to try to print out two lines: the original elements in the list and the elements after the list has been switched.

However, when I run the program, only the original elements in the list are printed. Am I doing something incorrectly??

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListADT {

  public static void main (String[] args){
    //create a list
    List <String> myList = new ArrayList<>(); {
      myList.add("A");
      myList.add("B");
      myList.add("C");
      myList.add("D");
      myList.add("E");

      //show the elements of that list
      System.out.println(myList);
    }
  }

  // precondition: x and y are >= 0 and < mylist.size()
  //precondition: mylist is not null
  void swap(int x, int y, List <String> myList) {
    String s = myList.get(x);
    myList.set(x, myList.get(y));
    myList.set(y, s);
    swap(1, 3, myList);

    //now console should show new list with elements switched
    System.out.println(myList);
  }

}
```

Comment: you forgot to  call the `swap()` method

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you never modified your list anywhere. 
I believe `swap` is what modifies your list but you never called the function `swap` in your main function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have never used `swap()` method. By  calling the `swap()` inside `swap()` itself, you were doing something called `recursion`. Which is wrong here. So I have moved the `swap()` call to the `main()` method. I have modified your code. Take a look at this.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        //create a list
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); {

            myList.add("A");
            myList.add("B");
            myList.add("C");
            myList.add("D");
            myList.add("E");
            //show the elements of that list
            System.out.println(myList);
            swap(1, 3, myList);

        }}
    //precondition: x and y are >= 0 and < mylist.size()
    //precondition: mylist is not null

    static void  swap(int x, int y, List <String> myList) {

        String s = myList.get(x);
        myList.set(x, myList.get(y));
        myList.set(y, s);

        //now console should show new list with elements switched
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program never calls `swap` from main.

Answer (score 0):

You ony added elements to the list and printed.
I believe you should have called `swap` before printing